# How do you get mac truecrypt to work with the latest Mac operating systems

Tags: mac, truecrypt

How do you get mac truecrypt to work with the latest Mac operating systems. When I try run truecrypt currently it says I needs at least 10.4. I am on yosemite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installer is a bit dim, it thinks 10.10 is less than 10.4

Try this workaround…

- Open the .dmg
- You’ll find the .mpkg. Right-click and “Show Package Contents”
- Open Contents Dir
- Open Packages Dir
- Install each of the 4 packages in this order:
  OSXFUSECore.pkg
  OSXFUSEMacFUSE.pkg
  MacFUSE.pkg
  TrueCrypt.pkg

Comment: Glad it helped :)